# How to add a item in a enum object which has been declared in final and compress to jar

Tags: java, android

I have a puzzle about a jar file. 
I need add a item in enum object.But the object is in a jar file and state in final. I really need a solution.Do you have some ideas?

[for example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgSjl.png)

```
public enum Resolution {
Unknown,
v_3840x2160_30p_16x9,
v_2704x2032_30p_4x3,
v_1920x1440_60p_4x3,
v_1920x1440_30p_4x3,
v_1920x1080_120p_16x9,
v_1920x1080_60p_16x9,
v_1920x1080_30p_16x9,
v_1280x960_120p_4x3,
v_1280x960_60p_4x3,
v_1280x720_240p_16x9,
v_840x480_120p_16x9;

private Resolution() {
                          }
}
```

And the method is:

```
public Video setResolution(VideoResolution resolution, Callback success, CommandCallback<Error> fail) {
    return this.sendCommand(new SetResolutionCommand(resolution, success, fail));
}
```

Comment: Why not just add in the source file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Decompile the respective `.class` file
2. Modify the resulting `.java` file
3. Compile the modified source
4. Replace the original `.class` file with the modified `.class` file (jars are just standardized zips, you can edit them with most common zip editors)

Comment: To be honest, I prefer your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot modify the source, you can't. Enums are generally final, they cannot be expanded.

But enums are also classes. So for your purposes you may define your own enum with  values of your choice, static method that accepts other type of enum to convert it to own type, and non static method that converts the new enum's value backward.

The code might lok a bit like this:

```
enum NewEnum {

  OLD_LIKE1, OLD_LIKE2, NEW1, NEW2;

  public static NewEnum fromOld(OldEnum old)
  {
    switch (old)
    {
      case OldEnum.VAL1: return OLD_LIKE1;
      case OldEnum.VAL2: return OLD_LIKE2;
    }
  }

  public OldEnum toOld()
  {
    switch (this)
    {
      case OLD_LIKE1:
      case NEW1: return OldEnum.VAL1;
      case OLD_LIKE2:
      case NEW2: return OldEnum.VAL2;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are some method use the original Enums, If do as you say, can these method work properly? Could you share a little demo?

Comment: As long as you don't modify original enum, the existing software will still work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it sometime.And no need to modify the method setResolution in old Enum?

Comment: No, you don't modify the code you import from elwhere. You may want to update external code some day and then you'd lose your changes.
Of course if this is open source, you're welcome to contribute and add some valuable features officially.